# Optimizing User Authentication Flow: Google OpenID to Notion API Integration in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, django, notion-api

iam currently developing a chrome extension that involves user authentication using Google OpenID. Following the initial authentication, the user is directed to the Notion API where a second authentication step is required to grant permissions from their Notion page to my extension.

I am exploring ways to optimize this process by transmitting the information obtained during the extension's authentication to the Notion API, facilitating automatic user authentication without the need for a second manual step.

Is there a method or best practice for securely transmitting and utilizing the authentication data from the Google OpenID process to seamlessly authenticate the user in the Notion API? I would greatly appreciate any insights, code examples, or recommended approaches to achieve a more streamlined authentication experience for the user.